# Add an image into the resources file

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I have a picture box where i display an image but i couldn't find the way to save it in the resources.

Here is my code so far:

```
private void imgContact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // open file dialog   
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    // image filters  
    open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // display image in picture box  
        imgContact.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
        // image file path  
        string imagePath = open.FileName;
     }
}
```

Comment: [ResourceWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcewriter) Class

Comment: yes the resourcewriter but i dont know how to use it in that case.

Comment: You don't know how to use the ResourceWriter to do what, exactly? Have you seen the examples in the MSDN Docs? Now, if, by chance, you are trying to add resources to the executable, then you cannot do that. You can: 1) generate a `.resx` (XML) file, using the `ResXResourceWriter` class. 2) Convert the `.resx` to a compiled `.resource` file or generate a new compiled `.resource` file using the 
`ResourceWriter` class 3) Add resources to an existing `.resource` file by reading all the resources contained, using the `ResourceReader` class and then writing them back.

Comment: If you mean to use a compiled `.resource` file as storage, IMO, you shouldn't. Use a zipped file instead. The [ZipArchive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive) and [ZipFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile) classes are really simple to use and provide a better mechanism (and also use less memory, if you're dealing with Bitmaps).

Comment: thank you for your answers. I have tried following Microsoft documentation but i wasn't successful. I can store the image by using the serialization(filestream) and it should be good enough for now. Thank you JImi